# Comment form not showing up without comments

Tags: comments, comment-form

My posts dont show the comment form unless that post already has comments. If post has one or more comments, everything works perfectly.

Everything used to work fine (that's why some posts have comments) and I have no idea why this is happening as I haven't touched any settings.

According to my settings, comments are enabled without restrictions and they are not closed after specific time. I also doubt that there's anything wrong with the code since putting `<?php comment_form(); ?>` on my template bahaves the same: doesn't show up without comments, shows up with comments.

I also tried to deactive all plugins one by one to see if some plugin was causing problems, but without results.

Does someone know what could be causing this issue?

Comment: most likely a problem with your theme's comments.php code.

Comment: To make sure there aren't any errors, I've tried replacing comments.php to a single line: comment_form(); Form still only appears in a post with comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I feel stupid now. The problem was that for whatever reason some of the posts had comments disabled. I did not know that the only place where they could be toggled was under "Quick Edit". Problem solved...

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly the problem I bumped into this morning!